# Node js and getIamPolicy of organization

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I can get the data using this command for gcloud:

```
gcloud organizations get-iam-policy ORGANIZATION_ID
```

I need to get the same data using the googleapis library for Node js. It supports cloudresourcemanager API.

My code:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const cloudResourceManager = google.cloudresourcemanager('v1');

async function main () {
  const authClient = await authorize();
  const request = {
    name: 'organizations/{ORGANIZATION_ID}/getIamPolicy',

    auth: authClient,
  };
  
  try {
    const response = (await cloudResourceManager.organizations.getIamPolicy.get(request)).data;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
main();

async function authorize() {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
  });
  return await auth.getClient();
}
```

It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?